# Launch the same Worklfow multiple times with different params

Tags: spring, pentaho, etl, talend, pdi

Is it possible to launch the same Talend Worklfow more than once at the same time with different parameters ? Do ETL tool even allows this, if so which one ?
I have tried doing this using PDI but couldn't.
Can Spring batch do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use *tRunJob* component for this, if I understood your question correctly. Please elaborate further on your need if this is not what you want to achieve.

1. Create a job which you need to be run several times.
2. Make sure to create context variables and use those context variables in the subjob. So for example, if an ID or filename changes, access the variable in the subjob:

   "C:\path\to\file\" + context.myfilename
3. To test this job, set default settings in the context variable.
4. Now, to use this subjob, you need to create another job. Drag and drop the subjob onto it. Alternatively, use a *tRunJob* component and select the desired subjob.
5. Now create the flow you need to establish the outer loop. Say for example a list of IDs or something else.
6. Put those variables either in the context and pass it to the subjob or pass variables into the context.

Answer (score 0):

In case if the jobs are built as standalone java app, just simply make a copy and change the context variables.
In case if you would like to make the system scalable, maybe a distributed docker system could be the solution like **Docker Swarm** or **Apache Mesos**